# What kind of information does Lifrey store in cookies?

Tags: cookies, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7

We have prepared a portal for our client and now he had questions:

- what kind of information does Liferay store in cookies?
- does Liferay keep the user's IP and can I somehow identify the user
  using cookies?

As a result of recent changes in the storage of personal data on the territory of the EU (The General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) (EU) 2016/679), this issue has become very acute

I must specify that we did not take any manipulations with the cookies in the development process

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure a voluntary forum like this is the right place to ask for information with this relevance. I can tell you what I know in terms of Liferay - if that's relevant for GDPR purposes, I don't know:

Cookies:

- Let's not look at session cookies - once you log in, of course they identify you. But once you close the browser, they're gone
- If you hit "Remember me" while logging in, Liferay stores your a long-lived encrypted cookie, because you chose to be identifiable when you come back, to save yourself from logging in again.
- There are a few "session state" cookies - you'd have to evaluate them if they're relevant. I believe that they're session cookies as well, but I'm not sure. The ones that I've seen were non-personal, rather giving some information about options that you chose (e.g. "don't show this again").

IP Addresses:

- I believe that the IP address of last login is saved when you log in, and kept until you log in again.
- There might be audit trails, e.g. events like "user updated" (at least that's where I found another 127.0.0.1 in my current test environment)

None of these IP addresses are used for user identification - it'd be utterly impossible, given that multiple users can hide behind a single IP address.

If you're using the Audience Targeting app, you'll certainly be remembered for longer, even if you're not logged in (that's through cookies again) and if you're configuring Google Analytics etc., well, that's what you get. If you enable (or keep enabled - not sure what the defaults are) twitter, google+ or facebook likes, for example on blogs: That's what you get (not from Liferay, but from the third parties). And if you allow login through a third party, as well.

That being said: Easiest is to operate all features of Liferay, then look at your cookies. Evaluate which one of them are long-lived and validate what they contain. Typically it's easily visible if they're personally identifiable (or risk being so) or if they just contain benign values.